# Is the question "people from what other countries are you in touch with?" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, question-words

Is the question *people from what other countries are you in touch with?* grammatically correct? For example:

> You said you talk to people from a lot of different countries except Brazil. **People from what other countries are you in touch with**?

If doesn't sound good, could you tell me how you would ask that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your example isn't grammatical.
You could say

> "What other countries are you in touch with people from?"

That's grammatical, but it sounds a little awkward, too.

In the context you describe, this would be completely natural:

> "You said you talk to people from a lot of different countries except Brazil. Which countries?".

Comment: Curious why you think the original answer is ungrammatical.

Comment: It's hard to put a definitive answer on why the original phrase *People from what other countries are you in touch with?* sounds ungrammatical, but it surely does sound awkward. **You are in touch with people from what other countries?** sounds better to me.

Comment: @urnonav Maybe "ungrammatical" is too strong, but it's not something I would ever expect a native English speaker to say.

Comment: @PhilPerry That does sound better, at least it's possible, maybe in a movie where a government agent is questioning someone, just before applying the thumbscrews. :-)

Comment: I believe that "What people from other countries are you in touch with?" is also an agreeable way of phrasing it (the semantics are slightly different, but the same basic meaning is conveyed). As to the original, I would be hard-pressed to come up with an established "general rule" being violated, but pretty much any native English speaker will agree that it is not grammatically correct. Sometimes grammar is just dictated by "you just can't do that" :)

Comment: @MicahCowan That does ask about the people, rather than the countries, but the latter would probably be included in the answer.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty yes, sorry - I should've been clearer. This is what I was hinting at when I said "the semantics are slightly different". One important difference is that a precise answer to my exact question might include multiple answers per country, whereas the original (and PhilPerry 's correction) asks no such thing.

Comment: What about: *From what other countries are you in touch with people*? Also, I don't understand why there are two downvotes on this answer.

Comment: @Cardinal Your suggestion works, and it's not too awkward.